# critical points of the multivariate polynomials

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations, maxima-minima

I have a multivariate polynomial
(multivariate polynomial function)
$$
R=R_2 R_5+R_2 R_3 R_5+R_4 R_6+R_3 R_4 R_6+R_3 R_5 R_6-R_2 R_3 R_5 R_6-R_2 R_4 R_5 R_6 -R_3 R_4 R_5 R_6+R_2 R_3 R_4 R_5 R_6 $$

The critical points of the multivariate polynomial determine a variety ,by the system
$$\frac{\partial R}{\partial R_2}=0,\frac{\partial R}{\partial R_3}=0,\frac{\partial R}{\partial R_4}=0,\frac{\partial R}{\partial R_5}=0,\frac{\partial R}{\partial R_6}=0$$
To solve this system, we can use Mathematica procedures
$${Solve}\left[\left\{R_3 R_5-R_3 R_6 R_5+R_3 R_4 R_6 R_5-R_4 R_6 R_5+R_5=0,R_2 R_5-R_2 R_6 R_5+R_2 R_4 R_6 R_5-R_4 R_6 R_5+R_6 R_5+R_4 R_6=0,R_3 R_6-R_2 R_5 R_6+R_2 R_3 R_5 R_6-R_3 R_5 R_6+R_6=0,R_3 R_2-R_3 R_6 R_2+R_3 R_4 R_6 R_2-R_4 R_6 R_2+R_2+R_3 R_6-R_3 R_4 R_6=0,R_3 R_4-R_2 R_5 R_4+R_2 R_3 R_5 R_4-R_3 R_5 R_4+R_4-R_2 R_3 R_5+R_3 R_5=0\right\},\left\{R_2,R_3,R_4,R_5,R_6\right\}\right]$$

The solution should be as follows
$$\left\{\left\{R_3\to -1,R_5\to 0,R_6\to 0\right\},\left\{R_3\to -1,R_5\to 0,R_6\to 0\right\},\left\{R_3\to -1,R_5\to 0,R_6\to 0\right\},\left\{R_3\to -1,R_5\to 0,R_6\to 0\right\},\left\{R_2\to 1,R_3\to -1,R_4\to 0,R_5\to 0\right\},\left\{R_2\to \frac{R_4-1}{3 R_4-1},R_3\to 0,R_5\to \frac{3 R_4-1}{R_4-1},R_6\to \frac{1}{R_4}\right\},\left\{R_2\to 0,R_4\to 0,R_5\to 0,R_6\to 0\right\},\left\{R_3\to -1,R_4\to 0,R_5\to 0,R_6\to 0\right\},\left\{R_2\to 0,R_3\to -1,R_4\to 1,R_6\to 0\right\},\left\{R_3\to -1,R_4\to 1,R_5\to 0,R_6\to 0\right\},\left\{R_3\to -1,R_4\to 0,R_5\to 0,R_6\to 0\right\}\right\}$$

For example, $$\{R_3→−1,R_5→0,R_6→0\}$$ In this set $$R_2,R_4$$ not available. What is the explanation for this?

There is more than one solution. Are all of these solutions are considered critical points?

How can I formulate these as critical points?

If you want to find a fixed saddle points  (local minima, maxima points ). What is the optimal way?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any point where all the partial derivatives vanish is a critical point. You'll have to analyze the Hessian matrix (the symmetric matrix of second-order partial derivatives) to determine the local nature.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you tell me some sources about  the Hessian matrix .

Comment: You might start with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test).

Comment: You have asked 1 hour ago a question (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2195347) with almost the same title ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes I asked this question. But when I generalized I had some problems

Comment: @JeanMarie Here , is more than one solution. Are all of these solutions are considered critical points? $$\{R_3→−1,R_5→0,R_6→0\}$$ In this set $$R_2,R_4$$ not available. What is the explanation for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing variables may have any value. For instance, ${R_3 \to -1, R_5 \to 0, R_6 \to 0}$ means that $R_2$ and $R_4$ may have any value, i.e. all the points of the form $(R_2, -1, R_4, 0, 0)$ are critical points, regardless of the values of $R_2$ and $R_4$.

Comment: Can I say that $$R_2,R_4 \in \Re$$

Comment: @Emadkareem: If by $\Re$ you understand $\Bbb R$, then yes. Notice that $\Re$ denotes the real part (of a complex number).

Comment: M. Thank you so much ...